# Odoo13 - Replace UserMenu from top right corner

Tags: xml, odoo

I'm using Odoo13 CE and I want to remove the User menus like Documentation and My odoo.com.

I tried by inherit the UserMenu template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo noupdate="0">
    <templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-extend="UserMenu">
            <t t-jquery="div.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right" t-operation="replace">
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="shortcuts" class="dropdown-item d-none d-md-inline-block">Shortcuts</a>
                    <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="settings" class="dropdown-item">Preferences</a>
                    <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="logout" class="dropdown-item">Log out</a>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </templates>
</odoo>
```

My Module structure:

```
{
    'name': 'Replace UserMenu.Action',
    'description': """
        Remove some UserMenu""",
    'version': '13',
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
    'author': 'Rafael',
    'website': ' ',
    'depends': [
        'base', 'web'
    ],
    'data': [
    ],
    'demo': [
    ],
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/change_menu2.xml'
    ],
}
```

But no lucky so far. I also tried with or without odoo tag, changing templates to template, but it doesn't work anyway. I tried to reinstall the module, commands like -u, -i with -d and no success.

I've tried this aswell >>> \https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/remove-support-menu-entry-from-top-right-corner-150211

Do I need to add some JS code or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Extend Template** this way,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<template xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="UserMenu.Actions">
        <t t-jquery="a[data-menu='documentation']" t-operation='replace'></t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Thanks